# Is the current behavior of `ge` in Operator-pending mode a bug?

Tags: cursor-movement

When motion `ge` is used with an operator, such as `d`, the operator acts not only on the current character (which is just inconvenient -- i would prefer that the current character be excluded), but also on the last character of the previous word, which in most cases makes the operation useless. Is this behavior a bug? There is no explanation in Vim's help.

As a workaround, i plan to set

```
noremap ge ?\><CR>
noremap gE ?\>\s<CR>
```

Comment: This isn't a bug.  `ge` goes to the end of the last word, so it would also delete the end of the last word.

Comment: Just use `b` instead.

Comment: @EvergreenTree, what for would i want to delete the last letter of the previous word?  By the way, `dw` does not delete the first letter of the following word.

Comment: @Doorknob, `b` deletes to the beginning of the previous word.  My question is about `ge`.  My usecase is an operation on what goes *after* the previous word.

Comment: `wW` and `bB` are "exclusive" motions but `eE` and `gegE` are "inclusive" motions. See `:h exclusive`.

Comment: Thanks for making me read help more carefully, @romainl.  I guess then this is not a bug but a design flaw.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I wouldn't call it a bug. Looking at `:h ge` this is said:

```
ge                      Backward to the end of word [count] inclusive.
```

Now let's see what inclusive means `:h inclusive`

```
A character motion is either inclusive or exclusive.  When inclusive, the
start and end position of the motion are included in the operation.  When
exclusive, the last character towards the end of the buffer is not
included. Linewise motions always include the start and end position.
```

This means, that ge will always include the character further to the beginning of the document, e.g. where the cursor jumps to. You can force it to be exclusive using the `v` modifier (`:h o_v`). But that means in this case only that the starting point will be excluded from the operation.

I gues what what you want, is something more like this map:

```
:onoremap <silent> <leader>ge  :norm! ge <cr>
```

This will make it exclusive to the char where the cursor jumps to (e.g. the beginning of the visual selection). If you want both ends to be exclusive, you can use this mapping:

```
:onoremap <silent> <leader>ge  :norm! vge oh<cr>
```

Note, that both mappings depend on your `'selection'` option to be at the default of `inclusive`. For a truly robust mapping, you would have to save and restore that option and use a mapping that works under a defined option value.

If you want the mapping make use of a count, something like this should do it. (For better understandability let's make use of a function):

```
fu! MyCustomGE()
    return "\<c-u>:norm! ".v:count1."ge "
endfu
onoremap <leader>ge :<c-u><c-r>=MyCustomGE()<cr><cr>
```

This way you can use `ge` for the standard Vim behaviour and `<Leader>ge` for your special case. See `:h <Leader>` for the Leader key (default backslash)

Comment: You mean like in dvge? Try it again. It will make it exclusive, but only the character the cursor was originally was on.

Comment: did you use d\ge
This works for me justfine

Comment: Ah, that is your problem. You also want this to be excluded? I'll update the answer

Comment: starting visual mode

Comment: I clean up the comments.

Comment: How about `:onoremap <leader>ge :norm! ge <cr>`? ;)

Comment: That won't work, since as soon as you type the ge, the operation will finish and the space comes too late.

Comment: Ah yes you are right

Comment: In fact, `:onoremap <leader>ge :norm! ge <cr>` already makes both ends exclusive (with default settings).

Comment: True. But I can't explain this.

Comment: Can it be made to work with `[count]`?

Comment: This should do it:

Comment: I ended up with this: `:onoremap <leader>ge :<C-u>exe "norm! ".v:count1."ge "<CR>`